# copy records that has epoch time and the records keeps adding

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Table A:

```
id  date         product    type
11  epochtime1    abc        T
12  epochtime2    def        P
13  epochtime3    ghi        K
14  epochtime4    klm        L
15  epochtime5    abc        T
```

TableB

```
id        date              product       type
hadgha     2020-10-14         abc          T
gsggss     2020-10-16         def          P
```

TableA and TableB are in same mysql database.

id in Table A and Table B are different even though the column name is same. First 2 records in table B is same as first 2 records in tableA.

I am trying to create mysql script which now copies the records from table A(except the first 2) to tableB and covert the epoch date to the yyyy-mm-dd h:m:s before copying the records.
Table A will be keep updating so the script when it runs again should not copy the copied records.

Comment: Read about MySQL [FROM_UNIXTIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

Comment: INSERT INTO TableB (date, product, type) 
SELECT from_unixtime(date), product, type from TableA
WHERE
id > 12

Comment: Does it work @Abhi?

Comment: It will work I know , but I am looking for a bigger solution where this FROM_UNIXTIME  will be the part of it.

Comment: @Abhi what do you mean by bigger solution

Comment: Yes, what do you mean bigger solution? According to your question, if I understand it, first you want to convert from epochtime to standard date/datetime then the next is to insert into another table but with a checking that a record will not be inserted twice. Question is, how do you define the uniqueness of the records? Based on which column(s) you'll check whether the record exists or not? `Date`? `Date`+`product`? `Date`+`product`+`type`? In your example tables, these three columns values matches. I don't think its `id` because the first table `id` value is different than the second.

Comment: The bigger solution is not only to have a script to convert epoch time to human readable but to have a script 1)which does the copy of records from tableA to tableB except for the first 2 records from table A because its already in tableB. 2) This script should also convert the epoch time for date format to human readable like 2020-09-15 14:13:53   3) This script needs to run every half an hour and such that the records that it has copied in its last run should not  get copied again. So a flag kind of mechanism or something which can take care of this.   Thanks.

Comment: where I am stuck is with 3) -  how to implement the logic in the script so that it knows what it has copied in its last run and so should not copy that again OR should start the copy of the records next from where it has last left and if no records has been added to tableA then don't do anything ..

Comment: _"how to implement the logic in the script so that it knows what it has copied in its last run and so should not copy that again"_ - first thing is, how the script will know which record it has copied before? Like I said, assuming if `Date+product+type` columns are a unique combo, make a unique index for those columns then use `INSERT IGNORE` for example. That way your script will not insert whatever already inside TableB.

Comment: @tcadidot0 - can it be done through cursor way where it store the last run info in some table

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "cursor way". Do you mean something like a log? And before the query runs it will refer to that log for last run info?

Comment: a stored procedure where we use cursor to store the result ..